# APScheduler (BackgroundScheduler) with Flask on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ecs

I have a simple flask application which is using APScheduler to run a function in the background.

```py
def start(application):

    @application.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])
    def hello_there():
        return jsonify({'data': 'Hello There'})


def main():
    application = Flask(__name__)

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func=my_func, trigger='interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
    
    start(application)

    return application
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

I am running this application using gunicorn:
`gunicorn --workers 4 --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 "app:main()"`

I am receiving the correct response when running this locally, but it is not working when the same application is deployed to AWS ECS . Sending a request to the endpoint results in a timeout.

[image]

Comment: Is the task exposed to the Internet via a load balancer? Is the target group healthy (health checks passing)? You are binding to `127.0.0.1`, which I believe means that it will only listen to local traffic, you should try `0.0.0.0`. Where exactly are you sending the request from? Can you show the details of how you are sending the request?

Comment: @MarkB Thanks Mark for the helpful comment. The issue is fixed, there was an issue with the binding as you said. Thank you so much 